# About the qualitative study of ordinary differential equations and books recommendation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

Actually I am an undergraduate student of final year and I have to take a course which is $\textit{The theory of ODE}$. Actually I really really do not have any idea about the qualitative thinking of ordinary differential equations and in my undergraduate degree I have taken the courses like real analysis, several variable calculus, basic metric space and topology, little bit of abstract and linear algebra and differential equations. So my question is how to approach with this course and is all the courses that I had taken in previous classes are enough to get into the qualitative study of ODE? And in a previous class when I took differential equation of my core course then I faced difficulties to solve equations and I used to forget the formulas of the ODE's how to solve a given equation. How much this will effect in the course of "Theory of ODE"? Which is the most important and useful prerequisite of this course and my last question is which books I should follow to study ?(Again I am mentioning I am really just a kid of this course and I have very little bit of idea of this course)

Here is the syllabus of the course of "Theory of ODE" that is provided by our university.

[image: The syllabus of the course provided by our university is attached below]

Comment: Boyce and DiPrima has a chapter on it that’s a good starting point. Strogatz’s book Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos is very well written and has a lot of material on it. [Brauer and Nohel](https://www.amazon.com/Qualitative-Theory-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/dp/0486658465) is good and inexpensive.

Comment: The fundamental strategy of calculus is to locally approximate a nonlinear function $f$ (difficult) by a linear function (easy). The qualitative theory of ODEs uses this strategy to understand the solutions of the nonlinear system of ODEs $y’(t) = f(y(t))$. Neat idea!

Comment: I don't know much literature on this topic, but a standard text during the 1970s was [**Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123495504) by Hirsch/Smale (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84280/13130) for differences between the 1974 1st and later editions), which was used for a course I took in Fall 1978, with Arnold's [**Ordinary Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0262510189) being a supplementary text. Much later (Spring 1990) I also took a course using the  Brauer/Nohel book @littleO mentioned.

Comment: @AnarghaSau: Check out: The Qualitative Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations: An Introduction (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Brauer, Fred; Nohel, John A. and Differential Equations and Their Applications: An Introduction to Applied Mathematics (Texts in Applied Mathematics, 11) 4th Edition
by Martin Braun  (Author)

Comment: @Moo: The book you suggest was already mentioned by both littleO and me. Perhaps you simply mean that you also think this book is worth considering?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Correct - I used that book in a course I took and think it is an excellent book for the items listed. Also, the second book by Braun is worth a look for some of the other areas mentioned in course description. For example, matrix exponential and the like.

Comment: @Moo: Sorry, I didn't realize you listed TWO books.

Comment: Regarding "formulas for solving ODEs", these methods of solution (exact equations, homogenous equations, power series method, etc.) will almost entirely be unnecessary. The closest similar type of "math reasoning" I can think of from those that you appear to have studied would be theoretical results involving the inverse function and implicit function theorems in multivariable calculus. I recommend visiting your university library and looking for either the books mentioned or similar books. In the (U.S.) Library of Congress classification, the books are mostly located around QA370.